# WordPress WP_Customize_Image_Control() not working with icon(.ico) files

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added an image control in my theme customizer to change the favicon. The problem is I am unable to upload .ico files. It works well with other file formats(.jpg, .png). Now I am using WP_Customize_Upload_Control() to change the fav icons. I would like to know is there any way to upload .ico files using WP_Customize_Image_Control(). There is no documentation available in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Image_Control) for this class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a couple of filters to allow .ico mime types in the WP Media Library.  Then I created a custom settings handler and control for the Favicon upload.

1. Allow .ico in Media Library

   ```
   add_filter( 'getimagesize_mimes_to_exts', array($this, 'add_ico_mime'), 99999 );
   add_filter( 'upload_mimes', array($this, 'add_ico_ext'), 99999 );

   /*Add Ico Mime Type to Allowed Extension*/
   public function add_ico_mime( $mime ) {
       $mime[ 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon' ] = "ico";
       $mime[ 'image/x-icon' ]             = "ico";
       $mime[ 'image/ico' ]                = "ico";
       return $mime;
   }

   /*Add Ico File Extension to Allowed Mimes*/
   public function add_ico_ext( $site_mimes ) {
       if (isset($site_mimes['ico']) === false) $site_mimes['ico'] = 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon';
       return $site_mimes;
   }
   ```
2. Settings Handler

   ```
   /*Setup WP Customizer Options*/
   public $transport = 'refresh'; // 'PostMessage';
   public $option_type = 'theme_mod';

   /*Handle Uploader Settings*/
   public function add_favicon_control($setting_id, $section_id, $label = '', $priority = 0) {
       global $wp_customize, $theme_namespace;

       $setting_args = array(
       'type'              => $this->option_type,
       'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
       'transport'         => $this->transport,
       'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
       );

       $wp_customize->add_setting( $setting_id, $setting_args );
       $favicon_control = new Favicon_Control( $wp_customize, $setting_id, 
       array(
       'label'         => __( $label, $theme_namespace ),
       'section'       => "ds_theme_{$section_id}_section_id",
       'priority'      => $priority,
       'settings'      => $setting_id,
       'context'      => 'favicon'
       ) );
       $wp_customize->add_control( $favicon_control );
       return $favicon_control;
   }
   ```
3. Declare Custom Favicon Control

   ```
   /*Custom Favicon Control Class    */
   class Favicon_Control 
   extends WP_Customize_Image_Control {
           public $setting_id;

           public function __construct( $manager, $id, $args = array() ) {
               $this->extensions[] = 'ico';
               $this->setting_id = $id;
               parent::__construct( $manager, $id, $args );
           }

           public function tab_uploaded() {
               $my_context_uploads = get_posts( array(
               'post_type'  => 'attachment',
               'meta_key'   => '_wp_attachment_context',
               'meta_value' => $this->context,
               'orderby'    => 'post_date',
               'nopaging'   => true,
               ) );
           ?>

           <div class="uploaded-target"></div>

           <?php
               if ( empty( $my_context_uploads ) )
                   return;
           ?>
           <div class="uploaded-favicons" data-controller="<?php esc_attr_e( $this->setting_id ); ?>">
               <?php
                   foreach ( (array) $my_context_uploads as $my_context_upload ) {
                       $this->print_tab_image( esc_url_raw( $my_context_upload->guid ) );
                   }
               ?>
           </div>
           <?php
           }
       }
   ```
4. Finally, initialize the handler

   ```
   /*Initialize Favicon Handler*/
   $this->add_favicon_control($setting_id, $section_id, $label, 80);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to extend the WP_Customize_Image_Control class to be able to accept .ico files. To do that, create a new file called 'customize-favicon.php', with the following code:

```
<?php
class SO_Customize_Favicon_Control extends WP_Customize_Image_Control {
    public function __construct( $manager, $id, $args ) {

        $this->extensions[] = 'ico';

        return parent::__construct( $manager, $id, $args );
    }
}
?>
```

Then, in your customize_register callback function, add an include to the new file, and replace the standard image control class with the one you just created:

```
include 'customize-favicon.php';
$wp_manager->add_control( new Custom_Customize_Favicon_Control( $wp_manager, 'favicon_image', array(
    'label'   => 'Favicon Image (16x16 px or 32x32 px)',
    'section' => 'some_global_section',
    'settings'   => 'favicon_image',
    'priority' => 1,
) ) );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to affect the JavaScript that WordPress uses to block users from choosing anything but a jpg, png, or gif file in the Theme Customizer.

Comment: the javascript uses a list of allowed file types that it takes from the extensions array in the image control class. If you've added the 'ico' item to the array, the javascript should allow these files to upload.

Comment: I've attempted to use this an I've found that adding ice files to this array isn't modifying the JavaScript.

Comment: Try temporarily overriding the original $extensions property with an extra array item for 'ico'. It's in wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php. If that doesn't have any affect on the list of allowed file extensions you see on in the frontend's JS, then you might be having PHP caching issues, in which case you'll need to restart the web server.

Comment: I noticed you typed 'ice' and not 'ico'. Was that on purpose?

Comment: Autocorrect fail. 

I've done this, cleared cache, restarted MAMP, the whole dance, but this isn't having any effect on uploading ico images. 

I've ended up changing your function to: 


`class Decode_Customize_Favicon_Image_Control extends WP_Customize_Image_Control {
public $extensions = array( 'png', 'ico', 'image/x-icon' );}`

which allows only pngs to be uploaded but still doesn't work for .ico files.

Comment: I built on Shay's approach and used the 'getimagesize_mimes_to_exts' and 'upload_mimes' filters to allow the .ico extension and 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon' mime type, respectively in the Media Library. Worked for me. http://pastebin.com/mWwdsAYb

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'myfile_upload');

function myfile_upload( $mimes ) {
  //Only allow SVG upload by admins
  if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
    return $mimes;
  }
    $mimes['ico'] = 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon';
    $mimes['ico'] = 'image/x-icon';
    $mimes['ico'] = 'mage/ico';

  
  return $mimes;
}
```